# Set width of p element with bg-color to automatically ajust to text length?

Tags: html, css, width

I have a p element with a defined Background Color that should adapt it's size automatically to the text inside it. I tried Setting the width to Auto, but the p element still spans 100% as visible by the defined Background Color.

how do I get the width to adjust accordingly without Setting the width in % or px everytime?

Code:

```
#job-xyz.titel {
    background-color: #dceff5;
    font-size:17px;
    color:black;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-left:45px;
    width:auto;
}

<div class="header2">

<p class="titel"><strong>Linux Softwaree</strong></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set width equal to content, use `display:inline-block`

```
#job-xyz.titel {
    background-color: #dceff5;
    font-size:17px;
    color:black;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-left:45px;
    width:auto;
    display:inline-block /*added*/
}
```

**Also,** you have assigned the css wrong way around
`#job-xyz.titel`
 should be
 `.header2 > p.titel`

[Your code demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q4Qdr/1/) and  [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q4Qdr/)

[**final working demo with proper css**](http://jsfiddle.net/q4Qdr/2/)

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` is a block-element and has to be set to inline via the "Display" property in CSS.

corrected code by "NoobEditor"

```
#job-xyz.titel {
    background-color: #dceff5;
    font-size:17px;
    color:black;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-left:45px;
    width:auto;
    display:inline-block /*added*/
}
```

Comment: just wanted to add an Explanation, but since you know did that I'll accept your answer of course. thx

Comment: lol...crap, i didn't noticed that you and OP are same people,anyway, you can always edit my answer and edit things from your own side, thats not an offense, removing my above comment...!! :)